# jQuery Product Display Page Not Displaying Details

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am linking to a product display page to show a books details. Unfortunately, the page only displays my header and navigation without showing the books details.

I am using VS Code with the Live Server extension installed for testing. I have a function that gets the book's ID from the URL, then passes that ID to the function that should then display the book's details. As you will see, I use quite a few comments in my code to provide clarity as to what functions should be doing. Most of the coding is handled in the JS file.

URL Passed to PDP page:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/book-pdp.html?bookID=ka2VUBqHiWkC
```

JS

```
/* sends the user to the product details page once the title is clicked */
/*ONLY INCLUDED TO SHOW HOW URL IS CREATED*
    /*send user to details page onclick of results (PDP)*/
        function productDisplayPage(bookID) {
            window.location.href = 'book-pdp.html?bookID=' + bookID + '';
        }
    /*end PDP*/
/* End Milestone 2 JS Code */

/* Begin Milestone 2 - Book PDP JS Code */
    /*Get bok id from URL*/
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url)
            url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
            var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
                    results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results)
                return null;
            if (!results[2])
                return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        }
    /* End get book id */

    /* Create product display page (PDP) */
        function displayProductDetails(){
            var queryString = location.search;
            var bookID = getParameterByName('bookID', queryString);
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var gbaObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    var gbaHtml = '';
                    console.log(gbaObject.items);
                    gbaObject.items.forEach(function (item) {
                        gbaHtml += `<div class="div200 border">
                            <div>
                                <img src="` + item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail + `" alt="` + item.volumeInfo.title + `" title="` + item.volumeInfo.title + `" />
                                <div><strong>Title:</strong><a href="` + item.volumeInfo.previewLink + `"> ` + item.volumeInfo.title + `</a></div>
                                <div><strong>Sub Title:</strong> ` + item.volumeInfo.subtitle + `</div>
                                <div><strong>Published Date:</strong> ` + item.volumeInfo.publishedDate + `</div>
                                <div><strong>Publisher:</strong> ` + item.volumeInfo.publisher + `</div>
                                <div><strong>Description</strong>` + item.searchInfo.textSnippet + `</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
                    });

                    //display results in container div container
                    $('#book-display').html(gbaHtml);
                }
                else{
                    $('#book-display').html("Something went wrong");
                }

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/" + bookID + "", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    /* End PDP page */

/* End Milestone 2 - Book PDP JS Code */
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Lee Baldwin - Milestone 2</title>
    <!--import external stylesheet-->
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- import jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--import external javascript-->
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

  </head>


<body onload="displayProductDetails()">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Lee Baldwin</h1>
        <h3>Kennesaw State University Student</h3>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.leebaldwin.website/Milestone1/leebaldwin_milestone1a.html">Milestone 1a</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.leebaldwin.website/Milestone1/leebaldwin_milestone1b.html">Milestone 1b</a></li>
        <li><a href="leebaldwin_milestone2.html">Milestone 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Milestone 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Milestone 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="grid-container" id="book-display">
    
    
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I inserted a console.log right after the var bookID = getParameterByName to ensure that my URL was parsing properly and getting the proper bookID. I am logging the correct bookID to the console, so the breakdown is occurring after that point.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the Move xmlhttp.open to the top and validate xmlhttp.status using 0 or 200.

```
 /* Create product display page (PDP) */
        function displayProductDetails(){
            var queryString = location.search;
            var bookID = getParameterByName('bookID', queryString);
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            
            
            // **** Move xmlhttp.open to here 
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/" + bookID + "", true);
            
            // **** Validate xmlhttp.status 
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 0 || (xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 400) {
                
                
                    var gbaObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    var gbaHtml = '';
                    console.log(gbaObject.items);
                    gbaObject.items.forEach(function (item) {
                        gbaHtml += `<div class="div200 border">
                            <div>
                                <img src="` + item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail + `" alt="` + item.volumeInfo.title + `" title="` + item.volumeInfo.title + `" />
                                <div><strong>Title:</strong><a href="` + item.volumeInfo.previewLink + `"> ` + item.volumeInfo.title + `</a></div>
                                <div><strong>Sub Title:</strong> ` + item.volumeInfo.subtitle + `</div>
                                <div><strong>Published Date:</strong> ` + item.volumeInfo.publishedDate + `</div>
                                <div><strong>Publisher:</strong> ` + item.volumeInfo.publisher + `</div>
                                <div><strong>Description</strong>` + item.searchInfo.textSnippet + `</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
                    });

                    //display results in container div container
                    $('#book-display').html(gbaHtml);
                }
                else{
                    $('#book-display').html("Something went wrong");
                }

            xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
    /* End PDP page */
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but those changes did not work. I did modify the status validation as it was missing a parentheses, but still does not display the details.